# Solving polynomial to get all coefficients

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Given an array of N integers where N can go upto 10^4 and each element can be upto 10^5.
Now i need to find the coefficients of polynomial p that is given as :

```
(1+a[1]*x)(1+a[2]*x).............(1+a[n]*x)
```

Note : as the coefficents can be very big so we need to find them modulo 100003.

Example : Let N=3 and array is [1 2 3].

Then as polynomial is (1+x)(1+2x)(1+3x)

So i need to put all its coefficeints in an array like here **6 11 6 1** as polynomial is 6x^3 + 11x^2 + 6x^2 + 1.

How to do it efficenlty?Please help

Comment: Why modulo $100003$? do you mean $10000^3$?

Comment: @nbubis No its 100003.I had taken this modulo so that it becomes possible to calculate and result dont overflow

Comment: Why? where does that number come from?

Comment: @n Its a prime number.No other reason.

Answer (score 0):

**Exponential solution**

Let $b_{n}x^n+...b_{1}x+b_{0}$ be the polynomial in discussion. You first find $b_{n}$(what is it?), then using Vieta's formulas you can easily derive all the coefficients. You can use it since you get all the zeroes to the polynomial(make sure to make the additions modulo $100003$).

**Hint**(for solution in $O(n^2)$):

Think recursively.

LE:

**Solution$O(n^2)$**

Start with the polynomial : $1+a_{1}x$, multiply by $1+a_{2}x$, then apply mod 100003 to all of the coefficients of the new polynomial. Continue in this way to get the solution... For the proof I would need to write a lot...

Comment: a[n] is nth array element and can you describe a bit how to use Vieta's formulas?

Comment: @ shooting-squirrel I want to ask how to do with computer not manually.

Comment: I mean i want an algorithm sort of thing

Comment: Moreover i am not having roots of this polynomial

Comment: I think you didnt get the question properly

Comment: But how can i compute product of twos at a time then three and so on.It would be very complex as N increases

Comment: Ok... that's true... it should be easy to get a formula. Think recursively.

Comment: Do you think recursive solution will help as N can be upto 10^4 ?

Comment: Also what should be recursion according to you?

Comment: How is it a hint to think of O(N^2) recursive solution

Comment: Using Vieta's formula would require a minimum of $2^N$ summations.

Comment: @shooting-squirrel Also do you think O(N^2) is most efficient approach here as N is 10^4.So 10^8 solution

Comment: Yes. What number does this project euler problem have?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented an $O\left( n^2\right)$ algorithm at

http://jsfiddle.net/xcrqoxk5/

I believe it's the recursive solution Shooting Squirrel is talking about.

Check to see if you understand how it works.

---

Suppose you want to multiply a polynomial $b_4 x^4 + b_3 x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0$ with the polynomial $ax + 1$. By a standard multiplication, we have $$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {}&{}&{{b_4}{x^4}}&{{b_3}{x^3}}&{{b_2}{x^2}}&{{b_1}x}&{{b_0}} \\ 
   \times &{}&{}&{}&{}&{ax}&1 \\ 
\hline
  {}&{}&{{b_4}{x^4}}&{{b_3}{x^3}}&{{b_2}{x^2}}&{{b_1}x}&{{b_0}} \\ 
   + &{a{b_4}{x^5}}&{a{b_3}{x^4}}&{a{b_2}{x^3}}&{a{b_1}{x^2}}&{a{b_0}x}&{} \\ 
\hline
  {}&{a{b_4}{x^5}}&{\left( {a{b_3} + {b_4}} \right){x^4}}&{\left( {a{b_2} + {b_3}} \right){x^3}}&{\left( {a{b_1} + {b_2}} \right){x^2}}&{\left( {a{b_0} + {b_1}} \right)x}&{{b_0}} 
\end{array}$$

Hence if the coefficients of the input polynomial are stored as $$B =\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{b_0}}&{{b_1}}&{{b_2}}&{{b_3}}&{{b_4}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$
then we see the way to get the coefficients of the output polynomial $$C = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {{c_0}}&{{c_1}}&{{c_2}}&{{c_3}}&{{c_4}}&{{c_5}} 
\end{array}} \right]$$ is to set $c_0 = b_0$, $c_5 = ab_4$, and $c_i = b_i + ab_{i-1}$ for all other $i$.

To compute the full array of coefficients, all we have to do is recursively apply the above procedure to each element in our set of $a$ coefficients, $X$.

Hence start with a coefficient array $C_0 = \left[1\right]$ (representing the polynomial $1$), and multiply it by the polynomial $1+ax$ using our routine, with $a = X\left[0\right]$, to get our first output coefficient array $C_1$. Then multiply the polynomial represented by this array by $1 + ax$ with $a = X\left[1\right]$ using the routine to get our output coefficient array $C_2$. Do this for every element of $X$ and we'll have computed the coefficients for the complete polynomial.

I've called the routine that does the multiplication "convolveWithOnePlusAx", and the function that computes the complete set of coefficients from $X$ "polyCoefsFromArray".

The last line in the script simply prints them out in reverse order. You can ignore it.

Comment: Can you please prvoide a pseudocode here as i dont work on javascript/jquery

Comment: @user3923257 - I've added a summary of the algorithm above.